# Mongoose, Remove document from double nested array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know its duplicate question but I am really don't understand why its not working

I need to remove documents from nested array

**( example remove item: requirement[0].update[2] )**

```
Schema {
    name: String,
    requirement:[{
        version: Number,
        update:[{
            date: Date,
            number: Number,
            description: String
        }]
    }],
}
```

code

```
File.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: req.params.name, }, 
    //, 'requirement._id': req.body.versionID

    { "$pull":  {'requirement.$.update._id': req.body.versionNumID} },  
    { safe: true, multi:true }, 
    function(err, obj) {}
);
```

[reference](http://roubenmeschian.com/rubo/?p=58)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
File.findOneAndUpdate({name:req.params.name},
  {$push: {"requirements.0.update": {_id:req.body.versionNumID}}
});
```

Comment: not working "requirement."+req.body.versionIndex+".update"  adding index

Comment: @ShibinRagh Try this: `{[‘requirements.${req.body.versionIndex}.update’]: {_id:req.body.versionNumID}}`

Comment: is there any other solution instead of using index ?  , Using  "update" array _id ? @dadwic